# Make changes in similar files depending on new commis

Tags: git

Say, I have a Java project in parallel branch (created from "develop") with several folders (packages):

```
com.package.source   - this is folder1
com.package.copy     - this is folder2
```

"copy" is created as a copy of "source" (with little changes, depending on new paths).

Now new commits (to "source") added to "develop" branch, so I want the same changes appear in "copy". Of course, I can manually add them in IDE, but commits appear several times a day.

Is there any simple way to do it using git? Maybe adding another branch containing only "com.package.copy" and merging every time?

Comment: What is the copy folder for? I am not sure what is your use case, but this doesn't sound like a job for git, but a general issue with your workflow.

Comment: @j4nw, we develop two applications in parallel; in a month will switch to the "copy" folder and remove a "source". But now a main application is created from "source".

Comment: Decided to change a task, so this question is not actual now.

Answer (score 1):

```
git checkout master

git checkout source
...
modifications. ..
...

git checkout -b copy  # Gets created on top of 'source' branch image..

git checkout source  #switch back to your 'source'
...
More modifications. ..
...

git checkout copy # Note, this time w/o -b!

git pull origin source # Get latest & greatest from 'source' branch locally?!?.
```

Comment: Thanks, probably it works, but I won't try, we decided to change a task.

Answer (score 1):

You can [`git cherry-pick`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) the common changes between branches, but that's generally not a good way of doing things. It would be preferable to keep your common codebase as a parent branch to the two "flavors" and do your changes there.

Comment: Thanks for an interesting mention. I like `cherry-pick` and probably can apply it here. You are right, it's an Android project, so it's possible to use flavours. If it will help me, I will write. But a ".../copy" folder will change mostly in several weeks, so I'm not sure I can.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your two package names are *not* branch names but actual paths inside your repository, i.e. there exist directories `com/package/source` and `.../copy` in your working directory, at least for a while until your refactoring or whatever it is you are doing is finished.

In this case, `git` has nothing that would directly help you.

In your case, I would take a look at any 3 way merge tool. `diff3` could be a starting point, or `meld`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Yesterday I copied parts of files from one folder to other.